# HTML 5 element for content?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Which of the new HTML5 elements should be used instead of div.container and div.content ?

```
<header>
  site header
</header>

<div class="container">

  <div class="content">

    <article>
      content
    </article>

    <article>
      content
    </article>

    <article>
      content
    </article>

  </div>

  <aside>
    sidebar
  <aside> 

</div>

<footer>
  site footer
</footer>
```

Comment: There is a new proposal for a `<maincontent>` element at http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/maincontent.html . It is is the matter of much dispute, for example, see http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/scooby-doo-content-element/ . Even if it comes to pass, it will not be part of HTML5, but of whatever follows HTML5. In the meantime, follow Matt Whipple's advice to use `role="main"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't answer this example in general, it depends on the content of the page.

What matters here is the outline of your page. Therefor, you can ignore all `div` elements as they don't influence the outline. Only use them if you *need* them as hooks for CSS or JavaScript.

The **first question** would be: Is the `aside` related to the whole page or is it related to the "content area"? If it is related to the whole page, it *must not* be included in another sectioning element. If it is related to the content area, it *has* to be included in that sectioning element. Here I assume that it is related to the whole web page.

The **second question**: Is there a common heading for the three `article` elements? Examples would be: "My favorite books", "Latest blog posts", or "Products". If so, you should use a sectioning element which groups these three `article` elements. If there would be no possible heading, you probably don't want a sectioning element here, so could use `div` or not element at all.

The **third question** (if the second question was answered positively): Should this sectioning element be an `section` or an `article` element? If your choice of using the `article` element for these three "things" is correct, you *probably* (but *not* inevitably!) need a `section` here. Whether it was correct at all to use `article`, again, depends on the real content. So it *could* be possible that you rather want

```
<article> 
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

instead of

```
<section> 
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</section>
```

Here I assume that your choice of using `article` for the three "things" is correct.

So the final version might look like:

```
<header>
  <!-- if this header applies to the whole page -->
</header>

<section>

  <!-- a h1 like "Latest blog posts" -->

    <article>
      content
    </article>

    <article>
      content
    </article>

    <article>
      content
    </article>

</section>

<aside>
    <!-- if this aside applies to the whole page -->
<aside> 

<footer>
  <!-- if this footer applies to the whole page -->
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

`div.content` can probably be a `<section>`. `div.container` should probably remain a `div`.

Answer (score 2):

None of them are made for that.  I'd recommend using [ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria.php) roles however.

```
<div class="container" role="document">

  <div class="content" role="main">
```

These can then also be used in CSS with selectors like `div[role='main']`

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend reading about the differences between `article` and `section` over at [HTML 5 DOCTOR](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/).

You will then be able to make an informed judgment about which sectioning elements should be used and when, and also when not to use div.

What I have surmised from their blog is that:

> article: Used for content which will make sense on its own!
>
> section: for content which is a logical section of either another section or an article (fine to nest these).
>
> div: still used for containers or as hooks for styling, which is something html5 elements should not be used for.

Finally the decision of using html5 sectioning elements can often be decided by the fact that it contains a heading (although this is not a hard and fast rule). There are a couple of useful tools to aid these decisions.

[HTML5 Outliner - online](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/)

[HTML5 Outliner - chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo)

Answer (score 1):

To consider this question as a constructive question, it needs to be interpreted as asking what the HTML5 drafts say about the matter. Then the answer is section 4.13.1 [The main part of the content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-idioms.html#the-main-part-of-the-content) in the W3C HTML5 draft. To put it briefly, it says that normally you don’t need any specific markup: just put the content there. Obviously, you can wrap it in a `div` element if you need to treat it as a unit in CSS or in scripting.

And according to that section, it could be marked up as `section` or `article` if it constitutes “a section of a larger work, for instance a chapter” or “an independent unit of content that one could imagine syndicating independently”, respectively.

This is a matter of coding style. No general-purpose software (like browser or search engine) cares about your choice here.